# ActiveRecord, Find by value of nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Phone` model nested to `Message` model. How can I find all Messages by a given number considering that `number` attribute is inside `Phone` model and not in `Message`?

This is what I currently got

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible  :phone_id
   belong_to :phone
end

class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible  :phone
   has_many :messages
end
```

Comment: can you post the model definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Message.joins(:phone).where("phones.phone = ?","123-456-7890").all
```

Comment: Just as a note, the use of .all is superfluous.

Answer (score 22):

```
Message.joins(:phone).where(phones: { phone: '555-555-5555' })
```